# Unable to run deno task start with invalid source code error

Tags: deno, freshjs

I have a deno repository of my own. I have recently switched to a new machine, and I have git clone'd that repository to my new machine.

Now when I run `deno task start`, it fails with this error

```
❯ deno task start
Task start deno run -A --watch=static/,routes/ dev.ts
Watcher Process started.
The manifest has been generated for 3 routes and 2 islands.
error: The source code is invalid, as it does not match the expected hash in the lock file.
  Specifier: https://esm.sh/*preact-render-to-string@5.2.4
  Lock file: /Users/john/my-project/deno.lock
```

I have read this page, but it is not telling me exactly what to do for my error

https://deno.land/manual@v1.29.4/basics/modules/integrity_checking

Comment: Have you tried deleting the [lockfile](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.0/basics/modules/integrity_checking) (`/Users/o.harada/dev/rises-unban-frontend/deno.lock`) and running it again?

Comment: Thank you, actually deleting the lockfile did the job. The answer from Samathingamajig produced the same error, probably due to the reasons explained in your comment to the answer (i.e. missing the `--` in the command)

Answer (score 2):

Based off of what that page says, the contents of one of your dependencies has changed since your original computer downloaded it for the first time, so the hash of the contents are different.

If you just want to ignore this, it says to use the flags

```bash
--lock=deno.lock --lock-write
```

which I assume means to run

```bash
deno task start --lock=deno.lock --lock-write
```

This will overwrite the current lock file with the new version of the code.

While this will work, the better option for the future is to specify the version in your dependency url.

For example, instead of

```js
import { z } from "https://deno.land/x/zod/mod.ts";
```

you should say

```js
import { z } from "https://deno.land/x/zod@v3.20.2/mod.ts";
```

(the `@v3.20.2` specfies the exact dependency version)

Comment: "which I assume means to run `deno task start --lock=deno.lock --lock-write`": This appends the double dashed (`--`) arguments to the defined task (in reference to the question code: equivalent to `deno run -A --watch=static/,routes/ dev.ts --lock=deno.lock --lock-write`)

Comment: @jsejcksn are you saying that you need to do something different than what I put as the command to achieve the desired result (such as put the `--` stuff before `start`)? I can't tell.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216945/unable-to-run-deno-task-start-with-invalid-source-code-error/75217123?noredirect=1#comment132792567_75217123) @Samathingamajig That's right — there's currently no way to use lockfile-related CLI args with the task runner except to embed them in task definitions directly.

Answer (score 0):

to fix the deno.lock

- give any dependency with the catch-all versions, a specific version from esm.sh or where you sourced your dependency.
  *example https://esm.sh/*preact-render-to-string@5.2.6 change to https://esm.sh/v124/*preact-render-to-string@5.2.6/ in the import_map.json file*
- you can find the version number by looking up the dependency URL in the browser. [image of looking up dependency link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg0nc.png)
- The version is placed after https://esm.sh/**version-here-v123**/preact-render-to-string@5.2.6/
- Next run `deno cache --reload=https://esm.sh/v124/*preact-render-to-string@5.2.6/ dev.ts` or `deno cache --reload=enter-your-dependency-URL-here src/dev.ts`
  *The dev.ts file is where all the dependencies are sourced unless you have a deps.ts file.  Running this command reloads and caches the new version to the DENO_DIR cache.*
- Finally run `deno task start --lock=src/deno.lock --lock-write` or like mentioned above
  `deno run -A --watch=static/,routes/ dev.ts --lock=deno.lock --lock-write`

This will write the newest version of the dependency to the deno.lock file and fix the issue

refs to docs: https://deno.com/manual@v1.29.4/basics/modules/reloading_modules,
https://deno.com/manual@v1.34.1/basics/modules/integrity_checking

Here's an example of a freshjs app `import_map.json` file with the exact dependency versions
https://github.com/denoland/merch/blob/main/import_map.json